# Open pdf documents with different Reader

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

I have certain pdf Documents (DRM) which I can only open with Acrobat Reader (Adobe LiveCycle Rights Management). Now I like  simply double-clicking these PDF files and Acrobat Reader opens.

What other PDF Document Viewer can be used or Is this possible without using Acrobat Reader?

Comment: I don't think so.  DRM'd pdfs still use the same extension on the filename as non-DRM'd, so the system can't tell which program to use.  (and don't you need Adobe Digital Editions for DRM'd documents - not Acrobat Reader?)

Comment: This pdfs use Adobe LiveCycle Rights Management

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the DRM, you can open those only with either Acrobat Reader or Adobe Digital Editions. There is no other reader that can open these files. The only option you have - granted you have the permission to do so - is to strip off the DRM with certain tools that you can easily find on the net.

Comment: What about if a rename the extension to say: file.apdf

Comment: Yes, if you are prepared to rename with a different extension, you could define a different program as the default for opening them.

Comment: Just renaming the file will not change anything. Technically, only the Acrobat products (Reader and Digital Editions) are able to open DRMed PDFs.

Comment: @mmb I meant renaming to another extensions which by default opens Acrobat Reader; Currently when double-clicking a pdf it will open "evince" which is fine for non DRMed pdf, but not ok for DRMed pdfs.

Comment: @ubnewbie2 Which extension could/should I use? apdf

Comment: You are inventing your own.  Choose whatever you like.